# Footables column sorting is duplicating rows in table, Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, footable

I am adding footables to a table but the table has to have a tbody for each row. This is because I am adding footable sorting and filtering to an existing system that generates the html this way.

It seems to be causing the column sorting at the to be duplicating the table rows each time you try to sort the table by column heading and I cant see why.

The table structure is kinda like this:

```
<table data-filter="#filter" class="footable table demo">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Job Title</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Name1</td>
        <td>Job Title1</td>
        <td>Active</td>
        <td>Description1</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Name2</td>
        <td>Job Title2</td>
        <td>Disabled</td>
        <td>Description2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $("table").footable().bind("footable_filtering", function (e) {
        var selected = $(".filter-status").find(":selected").text();
        if (selected && selected.length > 0) {
            e.filter += (e.filter && e.filter.length > 0) ? " " + selected : selected;
            e.clear = !e.filter;
        }
    });

    $(".clear-filter").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".filter-status").val("");
        $("table.demo").trigger("footable_clear_filter");
    });

    $(".filter-status").change(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("table.demo").trigger("footable_filter", {
            filter: $("#filter").val()
        });
    });
});
```

I have also set up a working jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue:https://jsfiddle.net/35ht6kup/9/

Anybody have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: I thought having multiple `<tbody>` might not be supported, but it is.(http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3)

Answer (score 0):

You could rebuild the table with jQuery, example (to be refined with a better selector than 'table'):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var thead = $('table thead');
    var tbodyhtml;

    $('table tbody').each(function(){
       tbodyhtml += $(this).html();
    });

    $('table').html(thead);
    $('table').append('<tbody>'+tbodyhtml+'</tbody>');
});
```

Comment: I’m not sure I understand this?   The tbody's have id's and stuff on them so I cant get rid of them dynamically.

Comment: There are no ids in your example. Working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f6LoacLL/1/

Comment: Yes but this is just a basic example to show the problem of the rows duplication on sorting.